# Firefox transition not yet rendered item

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, css-transitions

I have some elements hidden from the user using `display: none;` and are shown with transitions. Here's a simple shader do demonstrate the issue:

HTML:

```
<div id="list-shader"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#list-shader{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
    transition: background-color 5s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 5s;
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
listAdd.onclick = e => {
    listShader.style.display = "block";
    listShader.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(80, 80, 80, .4)";
}
```

This works exactly as expected on Chrome (The element fades in very slowly), but the shader is shown instantly as `rgba(80, 80, 80, .4)` in Firefox. I have narrowed it down to this theory:

Elements with no display have no calculated properties to transition from, and thus, act as if they were never given a default property, despite the fact that they were. Perhaps a bug in their new CSS engine? Doubtful.

Is anybody aware of a work-around or solution? I have already tried requestAnimationFrame on the line after setting the display, but to no success.

Comment: @Steven B. Please read my question more carefully!

Comment: That sounds like a Chrome bug actually... But it's easy to get what you want, by forcing a reflow after the display:block So e.g you can simply insert `listShader.offsetWidth;` between your two lines and that will work everywhere.